# Check if tuple is in every subquery result (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find every section that was held in every classroom that has more than 130 seats. Right now this just finds all sections that were held in at least one classroom with more than 130 seats.

```
select * 
from section 
where (building, room_number) in (select building,room_number 
                                  from classroom where capacity > 130)
```

Database scheme

- classroom (building, room_number, capacity)
- section (course_id, sec_id, semester, year, building, room_number, time_slot_id)

Answer (score 0):

You can use having to achieve that:

```
    select sec_id, count(*) 
    from section a inner join
    (
     select building, room_number
     from 
     ( 
      select distinct building,room_number 
       from classroom where capacity > 130
     ) a
    )b on a.building = b.building  and a.room_number = b.room_number

and 

    having count(*) = ( select count(*) 
                        from
                        (select distinct building,room_number 
                        from classroom where capacity > 130)a
                       )
    Group by sec_id
```

Comment: I've tried running this but it appears that this doesn't work. There could be (and are) multiple sections from different semesters that are offered in the same room and therefore the count(*) isn't correlated to the count of classrooms available.

Comment: This still suffers from the same problem. 
select count(*)  from (select distinct building,room_number from classroom where capacity > 130) returns 2 since based on the current data, there are 2 classrooms with > 130 capacity and the having clause returns the # of sections that have occurred in any classroom with > 130 capacity.

Comment: Added a distinct the the tuple building,room_number. Let me know if it works please. Did some additional changes

Comment: This should do it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists

```
select * 
from section s 
where not exists (select 1
                  from classroom c
                  where c.building = s.building and 
                        c.room_number = s.room_number and
                        c.capacity <= 130
                 ) ;
```